# Discord.js v13 hosting in Heroku will always send errors

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I'm getting this error hosting discord bot v13 in heroku.

```
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255971+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255971+00:00 app[worker.1]: Require stack:
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255971+00:00 app[worker.1]: - /app/src/Son-of-Anton.js
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255972+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255973+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255973+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255974+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255974+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/Son-of-Anton.js:1:41)
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255974+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255975+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255975+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255975+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255975+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12) {
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255976+00:00 app[worker.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255976+00:00 app[worker.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/src/Son-of-Anton.js' ]
2021-08-18T14:42:22.255976+00:00 app[worker.1]: }
2021-08-18T14:42:22.368305+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Is `"discord.js": "version"` in `package.json` in the version that is published to Heroku?

Comment: Could you share the dependencies (package.json)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install discord.js to heroku before launching your script.
Use npm for this.

Comment: please elaborate installing discord.js in heroku

Comment: It should be the same as how you would install it in your IDE. It would be installed via your console.
`npm install discord.js` (latest version)